# How to load Facebook Javascript sdk in Polymer Project?

Tags: javascript, facebook, polymer, web-component

I know there is a web component out there called `facebook-login` and I don't want to install for the simple matter...

I tried adding Facebook Javascript SDK in web component. In the ready call I added basic javascript sdk.

```
ready() {

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

And then in my  I tried adding this div but no luck.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>'
```

Please point me to the right direction.

Updated: landing-app.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" type="" href="../../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" type="" href="../../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="landing-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Navigation using App Toolbar -->
    <app-toolbar>
      <div class="toolbar-container">
        <div main-title>***</div>
      </div>
    </app-toolbar>
    <section>
      <p>Super Charged Bot</p>
      <h2>Helps pages to sell items through Messenger.</h2>
      <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
    </section>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
    * @customElement
    * @polymer
    */
    class LandingApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'landing-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          route: {
            prefix: '',
            path: ''
          }
        };
      }
      ready() {

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId            : 'your-app-id',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v2.10'
          });
          FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(LandingApp.is, LandingApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: what means "no luck"? did you add your app id? does the js sdk get loaded? please be more specific.

Comment: I have added app-id and also I tried slot suggested by @schrodingers-cat but still facebook login button not comming. I thought this is very simple matter...

Comment: again, does the js sdk get loaded? did you check it out in the network tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### note

**( Just a good to know)**
The facebook SDK adder that you have copied over to the ready function, essentially creates a script tag with the src pointing to `connect.fb.com` as the very first script tag on the document.
you are not scoping it to the component your are writing.

- **where** did you add that `<div>`?

  > Inside the shadow DOM? - If so, the javascript has **NO** access to your div

Try creating a `<slot>` inside your element's shadow DOM

Something like so:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
       <!-- your element's shadow DOM -->
      <slot name="fb-like-frame" ></slot>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

then, on the page where you are **connecting** your element,
just write

```
<my-app>
    <div slot="fb-like-frame" >
        <!--Insert your div here-->
    </div>
</my-app>
```

### Plunker

I have created a plunk .I have used your own code. Except,

- using slots.
- A dummy app id

Look at both index.html and landing-app.html

from the nav bar on the left hand side.

- Have you coded using `<slots>` ?
- Are you calling `super.ready()` inside `ready()`?

[View the component displaying the button](http://plnkr.co/NgQo8C)

Comment: Can you tell little bit clearly about how the `slot` will solve this issue, Please new coder here. Also I have updated my question.

Comment: Do not insert `<div class="fb-login.....`> into your shadow dom under `<section>`

instead, create a slot inside `<section>` like so:

`<section> ...... <slot name="fb-login-frame"></slot></section>`

Then, in the page where you add `<landing-app>`,

do `<landing-app> <div slot="fb-login-frame" class="fb-login... ></landing-app>`

**Also, ** move your fb SDK script outside the ready function It really does not scope it to your component.

make sure, it is loaded, before your component is used

Comment: the SDK right now, can not access your `<div>` because it is inside your landing-app's shadow dom. move it out into a slot for visiblitiy

Comment: - Where should I move my SDK?

**anywhere**. Just make sure, it has loaded, before you use your landing app

- *Where* should I write the slot?

Inside the DOM for landing app

- *Where* should I add the facebook div?

On the page, where you call your `<landing-app>` (**syntax above**)

Comment: Can you see the plunker I added? Have you coded the same?

Comment: Thanks and it worked.  I have index.html and followed by routing-app-component and then landing-app component. So I need to add slot on all the way upto index.html to work. Is there any better way to do this.... ?

Comment: Well depends where you use `<landing-app>`. If you call `<landing-app>` inside index.html, put the div there. If you call it inside `<routing-app-component>`, put it there instead. cheers