# Facebook "message us" button in polymer webapp

Tags: polymer, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to add "message us" button to my Web app made on Polymer 3.
On Facebook site I found information that I have to add the Facebook SDK script in html body:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId            : 'your-app-id',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v3.0'
        });
    };
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then add div to my page where I want to add the button:

```
<div class="fb-messengermessageus" 
    messenger_app_id="<APP_ID>" 
    page_id="<PAGE_ID>"
    color="<blue | white>"
    size="<standard | large | xlarge>">
</div>
```

But in Polymer when I add this code to the page nothing happens.
Should I create a special polymer element or I am doing something wrong? 
Any advice will be helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Polymer. You currently have an invalid chunk of HTML. As you can see in the `div`, they have several attributes which you need to input or select a value. For example, if your `app id` is `123456` and your `page id` is `abcd`, then you want it to be blue and large:

```
<div class="fb-messengermessageus" 
    messenger_app_id="123456" 
    page_id="abcd"
    color="blue>"
    size="large">
</div>
```

I can see the class `fb-messengermessageus`. Do they provide any styling CSS as well?

Comment: Well, I am trying to use it in a polymer app, so for me is related. Yes, in the  page_id and app_id I wrote my IDs. And its kinda worked but only in firefox an IE, but not in chrome. My assumption is that is related to polymer structure. And, no they don't provide any CSS.

Comment: Did anything show up in the console? Where did you add the `div` to, inside the html `template`?

Comment: Yes, in the template. This is what shows up in console: 
      <div class="fb-messengermessageus" messenger_app_id="xxx" 
            page_id="xxx" color="blue" size="large">
      </div> == $0

Comment: I can understand why it does not work now. I tested it myself and it seems that `sdk.js` is never loaded in the template. The reason might be that the `html template` is under the `Shadow DOM`, hence it can not access any global DOM structure because it's encapsulated and modular. The `sdk.js` might be also loaded in modular mode since ES6 Modules are not global. 

Trying in a normal `HTML` page yield no problems. Unfortunately, I don't have any solution for this but I hope these info might enable someone to find one for you.

Answer (score 0):

After days of studying, I found the solution. As Binh Bui said the problem is in the Shadow DOM. It's isolated from DOM and facebook SDK is not working in the web component. To bypass this and add facebook button to your web component we need to use "slots", more details [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/shadow-dom). But in my example I have two levels of shadow dom, so I need to make multi-level slot from index.html (DOM) file, threw my-app.js file, up to my-view.js file:
The SDK script I put in index.html, and in the body -> my-app section I inserted:

```
<body>
<my-app>
  <div slot="child">
    <div
      class="fb-messengermessageus"
      messenger_app_id="520865131680985"
      page_id="276570696236683"
      color="blue"
      size="large">
    </div>
  </div>
</my-app>
...
```

In the my-app.js file I added to my view the slot:

```
<my-view name="contacts">
   <slot name="child"></slot>
</my-view>
```

And in my-view.js file I added the unnamed slot:

```
<div>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

In the result the button is rendered on my polymer page :)
It helped me a lot this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990195/6821858) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403264/6821858).